# Search multiple same entry in database

Tags: mysql

I would like a mysql query that search multiple same entry in database.

For example:

```
**Username    Access_point  Mac_address            Authdate**

 ALAIN          AP01       00:00:00:00:00    2013-11-22 05:00:01
 ALAIN          AP01       00:00:00:00:00    2013-11-22 04:59:10
 ALAIN          AP02       00:00:00:00:00    2013-11-22 04:59:01
 ALAIN          AP01       00:00:00:00:00    2013-11-22 04:58:50
 ALAIN          AP03       00:00:00:00:00    2013-11-22 04:57:55
 ALAIN          AP01       00:00:00:00:00    2013-11-22 04:50:01
 ALAIN          AP02       00:00:00:00:00    2013-11-22 03:00:01
```

I would like a query which list me the same row ( except Authdate) and return it with a Group By on username to see how many times ALAIN was connected on AP01 last hour.

I don't know if it's clear for you ???

I had tried like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(username), username, (access_point), access-point, (mac_address), mac_address 
FROM table 
HAVING COUNT(username) > 1 
AND COUNT(access_point)> 1 
AND COUNT(mac_address) > 1
GROUP BY username
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Whats the primary key for this table?

Comment: Primary key is ID and mac_address

Comment: The table only stores **when** ALAIN authorized (in the AuthDate column) - from the fields you have posted I don't think we could accurately say **how long** ALAIN was connected for. Are there any other columns?

Comment: I don't want to know how long, but how many times. So in my example, the query have to return a count (4) for --> ALAIN AP01 etc ....

Comment: Do you only want the number of connections in the last hour? I included some code to do that, but the data above is quite old, so if you run my code against that it might not return anything. Hope thats ok, let me know if not and I can adjust.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your table is called - in your example it is just called "table" but I guess you changed this when you pasted it into SO.

If you want to count the number of connections for all users on all access points in the last hour, you can use this query:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfConnections, Username, Access_Point
FROM
    table
WHERE
    Authdate > DATE_SUB(Authdate, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
GROUP BY
    Username, Access_Point;
```

If you need only the data for ALAIN on AP01 then it would be this:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS NumberOfConnections, Username, Access_Point
FROM
    table
WHERE
    Authdate > DATE_SUB(Authdate, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
AND
    Username = 'ALAIN'
AND
    Access_Point = 'AP01'
GROUP BY
    Username, Access_Point;
```